# when i use to get phonenumber of my loged in user through firebase Authentication it gives this error .Cannot resolve method getPhoneNumber ()

Tags: android

[image][image]

i am trying to introduce firebase phone number authentication in my android project . but when i try to get the phonenumber of my loged in user through getPhoneNumber() method . it shows red error line and says cannot resolve method getPhoneNumber(). my getPhoneNumber() method in not working . it gets red when i write if(!FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber().isEmpty()) .. i have added firebase directly to my project through android studio instead of adding manually .

code my my gradle files is this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.anonymous.fyplogin"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

this code is of second gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: I have even added the parentheses but even same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phone auth has been added in Firebase 11. [See changelog.](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)

Update your dependency to at least:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
```